# What is a generic data structure for bezier curves or b-splines?

Tags: math, graphics, model, bezier, curve

I am wondering how you would model arbitrarily complex [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). I am not quite understanding the underlying abstraction yet of what a bezier curve is fundamentally composed of, as there are too many [equations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cubic-bezier-curve-implementation-in-c/). I would like to have a generic struct that defines a bezier curve. The [SVG path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) gives many examples of the types of curves you can create. They include linear, cubic, and quadratic bezier curves.

If a [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) is a better generic model, then that would be fine to use too. I am not familiar with those yet tho. [Difference between bezier segment and b-spline](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333055/difference-between-bezier-segment-and-b-spline). I guess "a B-spline curve is a curve that consists of Bezier curves as segments", so that is what I am looking for.

SVG docs say:

> Cubic Béziers take in two control points for each point.
>
> `<path d="M 10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>`
>
> Several Bézier curves can be stringed together to create extended, smooth shapes. Often, the control point on one side of a point will be a reflection of the control point used on the other side to keep the slope constant. In this case, a shortcut version of the cubic Bézier can be used, designated by the command S (or s).
>
> `<path d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>`
>
> The other type of Bézier curve, the quadratic curve called with Q, is actually a simpler curve than the cubic one. It requires one control point which determines the slope of the curve at both the start point and the end point. It takes two parameters: the control point and the end point of the curve.
>
> `<path d="M 10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>`

[Arcs and NURBS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072440/understanding-bezier-curves-vs-circular-elliptical-other-arcs) (non-uniform rational B-splines) are more complex than just plain bezier curves, but it would be nice if the model could be generalized enough to include these as well. Basically I would like a generic model of bezier curves/b-splines/nurbs to use in a drawing/graphics framework, and not sure what that would be.

- Must each bezier class be implemented separately, or can they be combined into one generic class?
- If separate, are they each basically just an array of control points?

So basically I start to think:

```
class CubicBezierCurve
  include ActiveModel::Model

  has_many :control_points
end

class ControlPoint
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :x, :y
end
```

But that doesn't quite seem right. A *primitive* cubic bezier curve, for instance, consists of 2 control points for each point. So perhaps (though, starting to get lost):

```
class CubicBezierCurve
  include ActiveModel::Model

  has_many :control_points, class_name: 'CubicBezierCurveControlPoint'
end

class CubicBezierCurveControlPoint
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :x, :y
end

class Point
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :x, :y
end
```

Basically, what is a good generic model for these 3 types of bezier curves (linear, cubic, and quadratic). If it's possible to make them all aspects of the same generic model that would be ideal (as it would mean the fewest number of classes), but if it requires class-specific other classes (like those specific to a cubic bezier curve), that would be fine too.

Implementation can be in any language, such as C structs, typescript, or Ruby models, Python classes, etc..

The reason for this question is so I can then build a DSL for creating curves on top of it, like the SVG path syntax. But the underlying data model will be the compile target.

For further reference, I will be researching these:

- https://github.com/twobitcircus/ofxTinyspline, e.g. [these structs](https://github.com/twobitcircus/ofxTinyspline/blob/master/src/tinyspline.h)
- https://github.com/pradeep-pyro/tinynurbs/blob/master/include/tinynurbs/core/surface.h
- https://github.com/orbingol/NURBS-Python/blob/5.x/geomdl/NURBS.py
- https://github.com/StandardCyborg/nurbs

This is just for 2D graphics.

Comment: Try to get a copy of "The NURBS Book" by Les Piegl and Wayne Tiller. I found it very useful when I learned about Bezier, B-Spline and NURBS curves and surfaces.The old Springer Books are often on sales, especially as e-books.

Comment: NURBS and Beziers are _wildly_ differents things. Bezier curves are interpolations of points. NURBS are interpolations of Beziers curves. One uses the other, but the maths involved is ridiculously different. So the obvious step one would be "have a look at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo because start at the start", but the real answer here is that it depends entirely on what you need to do. There is no "best class", there is no "best implementation", there is only "what is appropriate to the codebase and tech stack I have to work with".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most generic data structure for a Bezier curve is simply one that contains an array of control points. The degree of the Bezier curve is the number of control points - 1. So, linear, quadratic and cubic Bezier curves can all use the same data structure with difference in number of control points.

For B-spline curve, the generic data structure will contain

- Degree (D)
- Number of control points (N)
- Array of control points
- Knot sequence.

The knot sequence is simply a "double[ ]" of length = N+D+1. The knot values  need to be in non-decreasing order.

Comment: technically not true. That's one of the _two_ basic structures, the other is the "on curve point with relative left and/or right off-curve point" sequence data structure that's found in way too many older SDKs (looking at you, Photoshop path SDK)

Comment: Sorry. Never heard about this  "on curve point with relative left and/or right off-curve point" sequence data structure before.  Never saw it in any geometric modeling textbook either. Perhaps you want to elaborate?

Comment: not much to elaborate: it's a data structure that encodes only the "on curve points" with those points encoding their own left/right control points. If it's null, it's a disjointed connect, if it's a coordinate, it's a curve. I have no reason to assume it's ever mentioned in any school/uni textbooks, but it's been how Adobe's products encode Beziers since their inception, which makes it an industry standard that anyone programming Beziers should be aware of.

Comment: Perhaps it is an Adobe standard. But it is certainly not "industry standard" as I have been in this CAD industry for almost 30 years and never heard about it.

Comment: @fang: To my knowledge, "On-curve" and "Off-curve points" are spoken of primarily with the outlines of characters in fonts, such as TrueType and OpenType.  On the other hand, explicit encoding of control points occurs in SVG, for example, and in certain graphics APIs such as java.awt.GraphicsPath.

Comment: We all live in our own bubbles, we can work for 30 years and never know about something that others think is trivial knowledge because "everyone knows it". Adobe does not operate in the CAD space, so it's not too surprising that what's an industry standard in one industry (basically anything Adobe did is a defacto standard simply because they're the top of their industry) is not an industry standard in another.

Comment: Can this "on curve point with relative left and/or right off-curve point" data structure represent a general Bezier curve of any degree? If possible, please post links to online document for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A Bézier curve of degree *n* is simply *d* polynomials, one for each dimension.

Each polynomial is written in *Bernstein form* and has *n* plus one coefficients (better known as *control points*). These coefficients alone determine the polynomial. It may thus be helpful to treat each dimension (polynomial) separately, as the Bernstein basis is a rather intuitive way to describe polynomials. See also the paper cited below.

REFERENCES:

- Farouki, R.T., 2012. The Bernstein polynomial basis: A centennial retrospective. Computer Aided Geometric Design, 29(6), pp.379-419.